# Power output of ignition coil

Tags: power

I have a 12V battery connected to a circuit driving an ignition coil. The circuit requires 2A to run. The ignition coil produces 40,000V and the spark is measured at 50mA. By simple calculations the input power is 24W the output power is 2000W, how?

If I could harness the output power and my battery is 200Wh does this mean I can run a 2000W device for 8.3 hours, as the input is only 24W from the battery?

This does not seem right, what am I missing?

Or am I actually drawing 2000W power from the battery (over time) to charge the capacitors in the circuit etc, meaning that it will only last 6 minutes?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your input power is (probably) smooth(ish) DC. Your output power is short, sharp pulses. Measure the pulse-width and duty-cycle of your output and then average that 2kW over time.

Comment: Neither will you get 40,000 volts simultaneously with a current of 50 mA. Maybe the 50 mA is a short circuit current? It does sound excessive given the number of times I've pushed my finger into a plug cap when trying to diagnose bad starting engines. I should be dead if I was receiving 50 mA at 40,000 volts. Maybe I am? Is this hell?

Comment: The typical spark duration from an ignition coil is 1ms.

Comment: @Andyaka - Yes it is and your punishment is to answer questions like this  for the rest of your existence mwha mwha mwha (Devilish laugh)

Comment: Power may be high from stored energy arc in extreme short duration but energy E[Joules]=P*t is low.  24W/2000W implies < 1.2ms per second duty cycle and if >1000 Hz then is < 1us duration.

Comment: Tony, OK, so the power is delivered for a short time, but is coming from the battery. If the 2000W is being delivered in pulses the total duration of all the pulses should equal the total energy that the battery holds.

Comment: *Energy is neither created or destroyed merely changed in form*. The coil will always be less than 100% efficient  so, no, energy wise you cannot get out of the coil more than you put in.

Comment: Note that you don't get 40kV and 50mA *simultaneously*. The 40kV is *before* the air breaks down, and the 50mA is *after*. The actual arc voltage *while the current is flowing* is much lower than 40kV.

Comment: It may take 40,000V to strike the spark  but then the voltage will collapse (say to 4000V) as the current builds up to 50mA, giving 200W power while the spark lasts. But the spark only lasts a short time - perhaps 1 ms as others suggest - repeated how often? If it's 100 times per second, the spark lasts 10% of the time, for 20W average power. (100 sparks/second would be right for a 2 cylinder 2 stroke engine, or 4 cylinder 4 stroke, running at 3000rpm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read up on spark ignition systems and could perhaps start with something like [this](http://beru.federalmogul.com/sites/default/files/ti_07_ignition_coils_gb_2013_lowres.pdf).

You are correct in thinking that the output power is in kW, but unfortunately you left out an important element ...time. Spark gap time is in the 1 - 2 ms range for most systems depending on inductor values and total series resistance for the circuit.

Most Kettering systems have input currents in the 10 - 20 A range (I've not seen current in the 2 A range) at 12 V and produce about 40 kV in the secondary.

The currents that flow in the secondary (in the spark gap) can also very high (in the hundreds of mA). Initial breakover currents are typically in the 3 - 5 mA range, and increase to the 100 - 200 mA range as the gap voltage rapidly decreases.

In older systems with long spark plug leads the lead resistance may be several 10's kOhms and along with the higher resistance of the secondary coils this limits the current that will flow. With these systems spark line current may be design limited (by the series resistance) to 200 - 500 mA.

The power dissipated in the spark gap is limited both in time and voltage/current. At breakover (zero current) the voltage at the gap will rapidly rise to 40 kV, but once the plasma is created the instantaneous voltage will drop to only a few hundred volts. In older systems with a distributor gap, you had to create two plasma connections, one for the distributer and one in the cylinder spark plug. Losses abounded.

Modern systems typically use a coil-on-plug design which get's rid of one of the spark gaps (double the delivered spark energy), reduces series resistance and increases the plasma current (much 'hotter' sparks). Spark line current in these is still limited by design, typically to under 200 mA.

Read the document I linked to, it'll give you a good idea on modern systems.

Answer (score 1):

Power (WATTS) is often miss-understood. Power is defined as a moment of time thing. e.g. when on, a 100W light-bulb is using 100W all the time. A more real measure is power * time... and you end up with the standard you use kilowatt-hours you see on your electric bill. So a lightbulb uses 100w x 1Hour = 0.1KW.Hrs of electricity in an hour.

[image]

The image above shows a simplified version of what your coil does.

When your engine is running your coil is drawing 2A from the battery MOST of the time through the shown switch which is normally closed when the ignition switch is on. Your coil will draw 2A, so it is running at 24W most of the time.

When the spark is required, the a "switch" is opened. Since the coil is just a large inductor, the current still wants to flow through it so the voltage at the switch and attacked spark plug suddenly jumps to thousands of volts. A voltage high enough to produce a hot enough spark across the gap at the business end of spark-plug.

This happens in a fraction of a second. Most of the energy that is effectively stored in the coil is released in that very small time. Because the energy is released all at once, the Watts is very high for that very short period.

The switch closes after and the spark is generated and the coil is recharged with energy from the battery.

Because the spark time is small, on average the coil uses 2A, or 24W continuously.

Or perhaps more importantly 0.024kW.hrs.

You can think of it as the tipping bucket principle...

[image]

With the switched closed energy is poured into the bucket at a slow rate. When the switch opens the bucket tips over and releases all it's energy at once.

Comment: Your drawing is TOO simplified. Where's the secondary winding of the ignition coil?

Comment: I know @DaveTweed, I purposely wanted to keep it simple. If he doesn't understand how power works, understanding a transformer would simply confuse him.

Comment: So essentially I am filling the bucket up and then releasing it as a spark. Meaning that IF (neglecting component failure) the spark was continuous then the battery would only last around 6 minutes?

Comment: SO some extent yes, but actually no. If you had a continuous spark, what would actually happen is the coil (Bucket) would not have enough time to fill. You WOULD use more energy on average, but it will bog down to the point that a spark will no longer be available at some point.

Comment: NO..... you cannot ever generate a continuous spark from a discontinuous stored energy system. Why confuse the OP.

Comment: And by continuous a I meant more frequent.... i.e. switch open more time than closed. Remember the coil (Bucket) takes time to "fill up" again too. (ya I worded that wrong @JackCreasey) If you empty it faster than that it will never fully charge.